# Fluxo Alternativo no Spring

Tags: java, html, spring

Diante da situação: Estou na tela de cadastro de carros, onde posso selecionar a marca e digitar o modelo. Caso eu precise cadastrar um modelo que não tenha a marca previamente cadastrada, tenho um link que leva até a pagina de cadastro de marcas. O correto seria ao término do cadastro da marca, retornar à tela de cadastro de carros, e não ser exibida a tela padrão de lista de marcas.

Como implementar isso no Spring?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Como está atualmente seu código *controller*? Há alguma restrição quanto ao uso de parâmetros adicionais na *query string*? (a solução mais comum é redirecionar para o `Referer`, mas isso não é confiável)

Comment: poste o código, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais suave pro usuário seria implementar a tela de cadastro da marca numa View e numa Controller separada, e então, quando o usuário estiver cadastrando o carro, você pode usar uma Dialog (tipo a do jQuery UI) e exibir a view de cadastro de Marca apenas, tudo via ajax. Dessa forma, o usuário não perde o que ele esta fazendo no carro.

Outra possibilidade é usar session pra guardar o que o cara estava escrevendo na tela de carro, redirecionar ele pro cadastro de marca, e então voltar ele pro carro. Mas usar session não é muito o conceito do Spring MVC, que é algo feito pra Request-Response, portanto a primeira opção é a "mais correta".

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição RenanIf, realmente o usuário se sentiria mais confortável operando desta forma.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode enviar uma variável POST ou GET para a página de cadastro de marcas. Dependendo do valor dessa variável, você sabe pra onde direcionar quando terminar de cadastrar as marcas.

```
if(request.getParameter("flagOrigem").equals("1")){
return "cadastro/carros";
}else{
return "lista/marcas";
}
```

a variável "flagOrigem" foi enviada da pagina de cadastro de carros com o valor = "1";

Mas concordo com o @Renanlf que a solução mais elegante para o usuário é usar a jModal com ajax;

Comment: Essa solução funciona e seria mesmo a mais simples de se implementar. Porém acho mais aconselhado utilizar o "1" para fazer a comparação com possíveis valores vindos do GET, eliminando assim problemas oriundos de um possível GET vazio. Obrigado pela contribuição!